# Azure Storage Emulator fails after update to Windows 10 Anniversary update

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

About a week ago my machine got the Windows Anniversary update. Since then I have not been able to start the Azure Storage Emulator. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the Azure Storage Emulator and SQL Express Local DB. I've also tried the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239053/azure-storage-emulator-fails-after-adding-vs-2015-sdk). Neither resolved the issue. The MSSQLLocalDB exists and I can connect to it via SQL Management Studio.

If I try manually initialing the storage database I get this error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -inprocess
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.3.0.0 command line tool
Cannot reserve port: HttpSetServiceConfigurationAcl failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7).
One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again.
Error: Cannot reserve port: HttpSetServiceConfigurationAcl failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7).
```

Edit: At this point I've now tried uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio 2015, SqlLocalDB 2016 and Azure SDK 2.9.5. The storage emulator is still failing to initialize. If I re-run MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi I get the error: "Windows Storage Emulator Service has stopped working". Here's the log:

```
Action 10:33:33: RunInitialize. Initializing the Storage Emulator
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.5.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: An unknown error has occurred.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xffffffff: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xffffffff: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 10:35:57: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 10:35:57: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Initializing the Storage Emulator
Rollback: Copying new files
Rollback: Updating component registration
Action ended 10:35:57: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Action ended 10:35:57: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action 10:35:57: FatalError. 
Action start 10:35:57: FatalError.
Action 10:35:57: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 10:35:58: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 10:35:58: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

SqlLocalDB seems to be mostly functioning normally. I can create and delete databases from the command line without issue. Here's the output of SqlLocalDB i:

```
c:\Users\genslow\Downloads>sqllocaldb i
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV13
v12.0
v13.0
```

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Blame BillCo... Win10 updates are a complete mess right now, and M$ is using everyone as their beta testers...

Comment: Could you try running the command from an elevated command prompt? Or alternatively remove the "-inprocess" argument and it will prompt for elevation. Also, what is the error you are seeing when trying to start the emulator?

Comment: Thanks Michael. All steps I've tried have been at an elevated command prompt. Please see additional data I've added to the original question. The storage emulator doesn't currently install without crashing.

Comment: The storage emulator requires ports 10000, 10001, and 10002 to function properly. The error above indicates a failure to reserve these ports. Is some other application using any of these ports currently?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot reserve port: HttpSetServiceConfigurationAcl failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7).

According to the error message, it seems that the database already exists, so it returns the error. Please try to delete the database (you could make a backup of database file before you delete it) and then perform **Init** command. You could also try to use “**-forcecreate**”, which will force creation of database even if it already exists. Besides, please make sure if you run as administrator to configure the storage emulator.

Comment: SqlLocalDB -i does not report any existing azure db's and I can't find any stray .mdf files. -forcecreate didn't make any difference. It would be very helpful if this error message had returned the file name of the conflicting file.

Comment: [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/05/17/azure-emulator-crash-with-error-0x800700b7-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists/) discussed "Azure Emulator Crash with error 0x800700b7: Cannot create a file when that file already exists" issue, you could read it.